# Auto launch an activity when beacon comes in a certain distance

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, altbeacon, android-ibeacon

I want my application to auto launch an activity when beacon comes within a certain distance (in my case it is 1 meter)

My activity gets launched when i plug in or plug off the charger and when i boot the device but it didn't get auto launch when i closed the application and beacon is in 1 meter.

**what i want is if beacon is in 1 meter then activity should launch by itself.**

I am using android beacon library and following the same steps mentioned on 
https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html

My manifest file code is

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.altbeacon.beaconreference"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="false"/>

    <application 
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
        android:name="org.altbeacon.beaconreference.MyApplicationName">

    <activity
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"  
            android:name="org.altbeacon.beaconreference.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

My application class code is :

```
import java.util.Collection;
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.powersave.BackgroundPowerSaver;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.startup.BootstrapNotifier;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.startup.RegionBootstrap;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.Beacon;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconParser;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.RangeNotifier;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.Region;

public class MyApplicationName extends Application implements BootstrapNotifier, RangeNotifier {
    private static final String TAG = ".MyApplicationName";
    private RegionBootstrap regionBootstrap;
    private BeaconManager  mBeaconManager;
    private Region region;
    private Region mAllBeaconsRegion;
    private BackgroundPowerSaver mBackgroundPowerSaver;
    private RegionBootstrap mRegionBootstrap;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        mAllBeaconsRegion = new Region("all beacons", null, null, null);
        mBeaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
        mBackgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);     
        mRegionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, mAllBeaconsRegion);

        // By default the AndroidBeaconLibrary will only find AltBeacons.  If you wish to make it
        // find a different type of beacon, you must specify the byte layout for that beacon's
        // advertisement with a line like below.  The example shows how to find a beacon with the
        // same byte layout as AltBeacon but with a beaconTypeCode of 0xaabb
        //        
        Log.d(TAG, " region.  starting ranging");

        mBeaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
        mBeaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(11000l);

    }

    @Override
    public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int arg0, Region arg1) {
        // Don't care
    }

    @Override
    public void didEnterRegion(Region arg0) {

        mRegionBootstrap.disable();
        // This call to disable will make it so the activity below only gets launched the first time a beacon is seen (until the next time the app is launched)
       // if you want the Activity to launch every single time beacons come into view, remove this call.  
        try {

            mBeaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("all beacons", null, null, null));
            mBeaconManager.setRangeNotifier(this);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Got a didEnterRegion call");

    }

    @Override
    public void didExitRegion(Region arg0) {
        // Don't care
    }

    @Override
    public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (beacons.size() > 0) {

            for (Beacon beacon: beacons) {              

                if(beacon.getDistance()<1)
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "within 1 minute call");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                    // IMPORTANT: in the AndroidManifest.xml definition of this activity, you must set android:launchMode="singleInstance" or you will get two instances
                    // created when a user launches the activity manually and it gets launched from here.
                      intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                      this.startActivity(intent);               
                }       

            }

        }
    }        
}
```

My Main activity class is:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);    
    }

}
```

Comment: Seem like when you close your app beacon scanning thread stop as well so it will never call any detection .I can now able to  see where Beacon monitory code.

Comment: Have you checked whether the events, didDetermineStateForRegion, didExitRegion and didRangeBeaconsInRegion, could be triggered? How did you register them? Where is the code?

Comment: @Herry : I want to autolaunch my activity even if close the application .will it still scan.

Comment: @ManishButola For that you should use `Service` and do your scanning thread inside it then once you found near by beacon you can Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);                                     intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 this.startActivity(intent);   to lunch your activity.

Comment: @ManishButola Also i can see in your code that you have never bind BeaconManager which you should then only it will start for your RangerNotifier.

Comment: @Herry, no need to bind to `BeaconManager` explicitly when using the `RegionBootstrap` class, as this does so implicitly.   Also, the Android Beacon Library already runs a background service for scanning.  No need to create another one.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of the Android Beacon Library after an app is closed is different depending on how it was closed.  Beacon scanning keep going at background rates (**once every 5 minutes on Android 4.x**) if you use the back button.  If you kill it with the task switcher, it will resume scanning as soon vas possible (on power connected/disconnected or reboot).

Full details here: http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/resume-after-terminate.html

Your code looks OK to do what you want within the parameters of what is described above.  It is possible that you are simply seeing a five minute delay on detections when the app is in the background.  Scanning once every five minutes in the background is done to save battery, but is configurable.  On Android 5.x this delay is not present if you go from no beacons being visible to beacons being visible.

See here for details: http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/battery_manager.html

Comment: I want if i close an application from task switcher still it detect the beacons and if any beacons is in a range of 1 meter then activity( in my case MainActivity ) get launched. Is it possible

Comment: No, if you kill the app from the task switcher, it stops all processes.  That's how the Android OS works.  The app can re-launch itself only upon an external event (e.g. power connect/disconnect, reboot which the library will do automatically in your case.)  Until one of these events happens, the app will not be running and it will not be possible for it to detect beacons.

Comment: Hello David, I tried to implement the above code to run the app in the background with same scenario. I got an error that "BeaconManager is not bound to this service"  . Kindly let me know what mistake I am doing here .