# Auto Launch on Eddystone-UID within 1 meter

Tags: java, android, ibeacon-android, altbeacon, eddystone

I want to auto-launch my activity when a beacon comes within 1 meter. This question has been [posed before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29406325/auto-launch-an-activity-when-beacon-comes-in-a-certain-distance), but I am unable to get mine to work using/modifying his code.

Just like that post, I followed the same steps with the android beacon library through the [altbeacon github](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html) but still have been unsuccessful.

I also have "compile 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.7+'" in build.gradle file.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="org.communionchapelefca.ccsatx" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="23"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    "android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

    <application 
android:allowBackup="true" 
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" 
android:label="@string/app_name" 
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity 
android:name="org.communionchapelefca.ccsatx.SplashScreen" android:label="@string/app_name" 
android:launchMode="singleInstance">
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity 
android:name="org.communionchapelefca.ccsatx.MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" 
android:launchMode="singleInstance">
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="org.communionchapelefca.ccsatx.MAINACTIVITY"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>
    </manifest>
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.Manifest;
        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.app.AlertDialog;
        import android.app.Application;
        import android.content.DialogInterface;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
        import android.graphics.Bitmap;
        import android.os.Build;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.os.RemoteException;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.KeyEvent;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.MenuItem;
        import android.webkit.WebSettings;
        import android.webkit.WebView;
        import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
        import android.widget.ProgressBar;

        import org.altbeacon.beacon.Beacon;
        import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager;
        import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconParser;
        import org.altbeacon.beacon.RangeNotifier;
        import org.altbeacon.beacon.Region;
        import org.altbeacon.beacon.powersave.BackgroundPowerSaver;
        import org.altbeacon.beacon.startup.BootstrapNotifier;
        import org.altbeacon.beacon.startup.RegionBootstrap;

        import java.util.Collection;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements BootstrapNotifier, RangeNotifier {
    public static final String TAG = "MainActivityCCSATX";
    private WebView mWebView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
        private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION = 1;


            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

                progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

                WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
                webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                mWebView.loadUrl("http://communionchapelefca.org/edy-home");
                mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());

                // begin code for bluetooth permission for android 6
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    // Android M Permission checkâ€¨
                    if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                        builder.setTitle("This app needs location access to find Communion Chapel beacons");
                        builder.setMessage("Please grant location access so this app can detect Communion Chapel beacons.");
                        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                        builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION);
                            }
                        });
                        builder.show();
                    }
                }

                mAllBeaconsRegion = new Region("all beacons", null, null, null);
                mBeaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
                mBackgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);
                mRegionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, mAllBeaconsRegion);

                // By default the AndroidBeaconLibrary will only find AltBeacons.  If you wish to make it
                // find a different type of beacon, you must specify the byte layout for that beacon's
                // advertisement with a line like below.  The example shows how to find a beacon with the
                // same byte layout as AltBeacon but with a beaconTypeCode of 0xaabb
                //
                Log.d(TAG, " region.  starting ranging");

                mBeaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
                mBeaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(11000l);

            }

            @Override
            public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                                   String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
                switch (requestCode) {
                    case PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION: {
                        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "coarse location permission granted");
                        } else {
                            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                            builder.setTitle("Functionality limited");
                            builder.setMessage("Since location access has not been granted, this app will not be able to discover beacons when in the background.");
                            builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                            builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                                }

                            });
                            builder.show();
                        }
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }

        // end code for bluetooth permission for android 6



    private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{


        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url)
        {
            webView.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            progressBar.setVisibility(view.GONE);
        }

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    { //if back key is pressed
        if((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)&& mWebView.canGoBack())
        {
            mWebView.goBack();
            return true;

        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                MainActivity.this);

        // set title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Exit");

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Do you really want to exit?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, close
                        // current activity
                        MainActivity.this.finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, just close
                        // the dialog box and do nothing
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        // create alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        // show it
        alertDialog.show();
    }


    private RegionBootstrap regionBootstrap;
    private BeaconManager mBeaconManager;
    private Region region;
    private Region mAllBeaconsRegion;
    private BackgroundPowerSaver mBackgroundPowerSaver;
    private RegionBootstrap mRegionBootstrap;

    @Override
    public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int arg0, Region arg1) {
        // Don't care
    }

    @Override
    public void didEnterRegion(Region arg0) {

        mRegionBootstrap.disable();
        // This call to disable will make it so the activity below only gets launched the first time a beacon is seen (until the next time the app is launched)
        // if you want the Activity to launch every single time beacons come into view, remove this call.
        try {

            mBeaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("all beacons", null, null, null));
            mBeaconManager.setRangeNotifier(this);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Got a didEnterRegion call");

    }

    @Override
    public void didExitRegion(Region arg0) {
        // Don't care
    }

    @Override
    public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (beacons.size() > 0) {

            for (Beacon beacon: beacons) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Found a beacon, getting distance");
                if(beacon.getDistance()<1)
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "within 1 minute call");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                    // IMPORTANT: in the AndroidManifest.xml definition of this activity, you must set android:launchMode="singleInstance" or you will get two instances
                    // created when a user launches the activity manually and it gets launched from here.
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    this.startActivity(intent);
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

LogCat from fatal error:

```
01-28 17:23:38.819  6549  6724 D MainActivityCCSATX: Got a didEnterRegion call
01-28 17:23:38.824  6549  6549 D BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
01-28 17:23:38.824  6549  6549 D BluetoothLeScanner: could not find callback wrapper
01-28 17:23:38.824  6549  6549 D BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
01-28 17:23:38.824  6549  6549 D BluetoothLeScanner: could not find callback wrapper
01-28 17:23:39.444  6549  6549 W cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 6549
01-28 17:23:40.023  6549  6549 W cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 6549
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about why you have been unsuccessful?  Does the code get inside the` if (beacons.size() > 0)` block?  Does it get inside the `if(beacon.getDistance()<1)` block?

Comment: That's the thing; I dont know why its unsuccessful. I have my beacon (Eddy-UID) plugged in and broadcasting (confirmed with RadBeacon). However, whenever my device with the app installed (which was opened and ran at least once) gets less than 1 meter from the beacon, it does not open the app (either foreground or background). Is my code wrong? How can I test what you suggested?

Answer (score 0):

A few tips:

1. Try adding a debug line `Log.d("Distance:"+beacon.get Distance());` before you check for Distance < 1.  Then run the app while watching LogCat output looking for that log line.
2. Understand that if you have Android 4.x, it may take up to five minutes to detect in the background.
3. It is always easier to get apps working in the foreground first, and then add background capability.  Make sure you can write code to detect your beacon in the foreground.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Im running Android 6 on a Nexus 9. In radius network other apps im able to see a beacon in less than 5 seconds.

I ran logcat and got a huge file. Ive attached the output in the OP since I dont have enough room in this box.

Comment: I also looked further down in the logcat file and found that its found the beacon and started parsing but then produces a warning about ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator. Ive read elsewhere online that this is a parsing issue, but isnt my code paring the beacon?

Comment: After doing more research I believe it to be a Android6 resulting error. Marshmellow requires permission "ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION" or "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" and a prompt to the user to allow this permission. I added the Runtime Permission code from here: http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2015/09/29/is-your-beacon-app-ready-for-android-6.html

@davidgyoung can you look at my revised MyApplication.java above? I imported every class but requestPermission and PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION dont allow importing the class. Any idea why?

Comment: The code shows two `onCreate`  methods.  Is this a typo?  Are you saying you cannot import `PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION`?  Are you targeting SDK 23 in Android studio?  You must do so to detect in the background on Android 6+.

Comment: @daviggyoung i saw what you stated in your comment and adjusted it. I have a min SDK of 19 and target of 23.

I spend the whole day slaving away at this and this and this is what I did. I almost started from scratch to try and get this to work and I think Im close. I combined my MyApplicationName with my MainActivity class. This allowed me to successfully request permissions for COURSE_LOCATION and it got me to detecting beacons, parsing them, and then seeing them enter a region. In the logcat above it throws a "BluetoothLeScanner: could not find callback wrapper error"; did I miss something?

Comment: You can ignore that log line about "could not find callback wrapper".  Do you ever see "Found a beacon, getting distance"?

Answer (score 0):

With help from davidgyoung's code posted on [github](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference), I was able to solve the problem.